# Getting an image vertically aligned in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried various other solutions posted on stackoverflow that worked for others, but unfortunately I haven't been able to get an image to properly center vertically.  I'm hoping someone can figure out what is needed.

This is the right corner of a top nav bar, and I put red border to make it easier to see.  I would like the photo on the right to be centered vertically within the container box, as you can see by the gap under the photo it is not vertically centered.

Please note:  I can get it to work using position:relative; bottom:-5px; on the image, but I was wondering if there was another/better way.

[image: top nav]

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-userOptions" class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="row">
      <a href="#">
         <div class="col-xs-6" ng-click="create_show=true" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div  style="height:60px">
               <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:60px; border:1px solid red;"></i> 
            </div>
            <div>
               Create
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
         <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red;"  >
            <div style="height:60px; vertical-align:middle; float:none; display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;">
               <img   src="img/loggedIn/profilePic.jpg" height="52" width="52" style="border:1px solid red">
            </div>
            <div>
               Account
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- end nav-userOptions -->
```

CSS:

```
#nav-userOptions {
    text-align: center;
    color:#20a0d8;
}

#nav-userOptions a {
    color:#20a0d8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying `line-height: 60px` to the `img`.

Or, another solution:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a css style `display:table-cell` ?
It works if you defined a height for a image container

```
div.img-container{
       display:table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle; 
       height: 60px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following css.

```
img{
 vertican-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `top` attribute in img

```
img {
   position: relative;
   top: 5%;
}
```